# How do you smooth the edges a primitive using a shader?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, jogl, antialiasing

What is the simplest technique used to soften the edges of a simple primitive such as `GL_TRIANGLES` in OpenGL using a fragment shader?

I've read that within a `GL_BLEND` context, we can modulate the alpha values of a fragment depending on it's proximity to an edge; but how is this achieved efficiently in practice?

Comment: multi sampling anti-aliasing

Comment: I've read about this, but some hardware doesn't support it. I've seen that it's possible to achieve this effect within a shader, as outlined in this article: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html
The reason I can't use the code provided is because it draws an aliased curve. I was hoping to find a method which can be used for smoothing arbitrary polygon edges.

Comment: If you soften the edges using blending, you are going to have to draw your geometry back-to-front. That is probably not practical, but that is essentially how polygon smoothing worked in desktop OpenGL before it was removed. From your platform tag, I will assume that you are using OpenGL ES - multisample renderbuffers are not core in OpenGL ES 2.0 unfortunately. However, MSAA is pretty standard on hardware that supports pixel shaders - it was created to reduce the number of times the pixel shader had to run. It is probably exposed at the EGL level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edges of a primitive can be smoothed using anti aliasing.

OpenGL offers [multisample buffers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling) to allow hardware-accelerated aliasing of an image, however this feature is not supported by all platforms due to it's dependence on dedicated hardware buffers on board the GPU. An alternative method is to [render your display to a texture using a FrameBuffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples), and then pass the rendered texture through Timothy Lottes' [Fast Approximate Anti Aliasing (FXAA)](http://www.geeks3d.com/20110405/fxaa-fast-approximate-anti-aliasing-demo-glsl-opengl-test-radeon-geforce/) shader, which requires a single pass.

Comment: FXAA on typical Android device will run pretty slow.